# Cutting donuts in QGIS

Tags: qgis, donut-polygons

I'm trying to cut donut polygons ready to go into a system that can't display them. Basically the exact opposite of this post: [How to convert fake donut holes in polygons to real ones?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28906/how-to-convert-fake-donut-holes-in-polygons-to-real-ones)

I want to cut at any point so that the polygon no longer contains an inner ring(s). (Ideally the shortest path but I don't really care.)

Is this possible in QGIS?

Comment: At least QGIS does not report such polygons as topology errors. Tested with `POLYGON (( 192 471, 473 507, 469 292, 371 280, 375 180, 564 184, 564 282, 469 292, 473 507, 755 490, 717 93, 177 80, 192 471 ))` However, I do not know how to convert holes into outer ring loops with QGIS. I think that this was rather common requirement in GIS software of the 1990s but not nowadays.

Comment: Im using software that doesnt support spatial data yet and uses those same 90's standards for drawing polygons.  Any other open source tools you know of that can do this?

Comment: Do you need an automated solution or is manual sufficient?

Comment: Not manual to the extent i actually have to draw slice lines for each polygon.  As long as there are a series of steps I can use by hand on a large overlay i dont mind.